# Was or is this the thing that you mentioned to me yesterday

Tags: grammar

Because we usually use past tense for the past and present tense for present and fact. This question is a past but it is a fact (I guess). I'm confused whether to use is or was for this question.

Answer (score 2):

Both are fine.

If you use the present, you are putting a bit of emphasis on the fact that the thing is still here; if you use the past, you are not.